# EXCEL conditional formatting based on 3 different dates. Once passed each of the dates X column changes word

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a shipping Lineup. I have an ETA an ETB and a ETD date column for each ship. I also have a Status column to display either Expected,Waiting,Loading,Sailed. If today's date is pre ETA date I want my status column to display "expected". Once we pass the ETA date, I want the status column to display "Waiting". Once we pass the ETB date the status should be "Loading". And finally once we pass the ETD date the status should be saying "sailed".
Any idea how to do this on a excel 2010 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume ETA is in column A, ETB is column B, and ETD is column C. Put this formula in column D, starting in D1 and drag down.

```
=if(today()>C1, "Sailed", if(today()>B1,"Loading",if(today()>A1,"Waiting","Expected")))
```

This works by testing each successive criteria - if TODAY() [which is an automatic excel function which brings up the day's date] is later than the ETD date, and if not, if it is larger than the ETB date, and if not, if it is larger than the ETA date [if not, automatically it becomes "Expecting"].

This is not really 'conditional formatting'. Conditional formatting is a special option to add a formula which impacts the formatting of a cell, and not its value.

Comment: @CzukDee Great - would you mind clicking 'Accept Answer' next to my response?